# How to parse Google map using web scraping method to get all property address in python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I want all property address in Poland by web scraping of Google map using Beautiful soup lib. Is it possible to parse html data behind Google map search to get data?

We Need a dataframe which contains all address in Poland.

If any one can help me that I will be grateful.

Comment: Have a look here: https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing

Comment: you can also take a look at Google Map Developer: https://developers.google.com/maps

Comment: Why not openstreetmap?